# Can the “while attuned” powers of Solarian stellar revelations be used while attuned to either mode, or only the matching one?

Tags: starfinder

I’m having trouble finding an official clarification of this, so I’m wondering if anyone has found a ruling:

Solarians gain powers known as stellar revelations. These are either “photon” or “graviton” revelations. It is specifically mentioned they can be used out of combat, though most include improved effects or separate powers that can only be used “while attuned” - a state a Solarian enters during combat. They may be photon or graviton attuned, at the player’s choice, and are able to increase their level of attunement each round until they become fully attuned to one or the other. However, apart from the very powerful “zenith revelations”, nowhere in the rules mentions whether photon revelations may only be used while photon attuned, or graviton revelations only while graviton attuned. The revelations themselves usually say “while attuned or fully attuned” for the more powerful effects, without mentioning the mode, and there’s no general rule in the class feature that answers this question.

Is there an official ruling on whether the “only while attuned” power of a photon revelation can be used when the character is graviton attuned, or vice versa? I suspect the answer is yes but it’s hard to tell based on the core rules.

Comment: Your wording is a little confusing as your title implies you're not sure if you can use a revelation at all if you're not in the right mode, but your text seems to acknowledge that you can use a revelation in any mode but that it's the "when attuned/fully attuned" bit which is causing you confusion (and which caused me some confusion when trying to answer this question). You may wish to edit this for clarity.

Comment: Thanks Carcer - I’ll amend it! I mean the “while attuned” powers (its clear the other minor powers can be used at any time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Stellar Revelations can be used in any mode (including unattuned), but only get more powerful when attuned to the appropriate mode.

The [Stellar Mode](http://www.starjammersrd.com/classes/solarian/#Stellar_Mode_Su_1st_Level) ability description states:

> Some of your stellar revelations are graviton powers and get stronger if you’re graviton-attuned.

and...

> Some of your stellar revelations are photon powers and get stronger if you’re photon-attuned.

The intent is clear - your photon revelations are more powerful (invoking the "when attuned or fully attuned" paragraph of the revelation description) when you are attuned to photon mode, and vice versa for graviton revelations. Photon revelations do not get more powerful when you are graviton-attuned, nor graviton revelations more powerful when you are photon-attuned - but the base effect of the revelation can be used no matter what mode you are in.

Though the full text descriptions of individual stellar revelations do not specify whether you need to be attuned to photon or graviton mode to activate the stronger effect, they are probably written this way for brevity's sake, as each revelation is clearly presented as being either a Photon or Graviton revelation, and the description of the Stellar Mode ability states they get better when you are attuned to the right mode.

Comment: Thanks Carcer - not sure how I missed that! Clearly in my re-reading I was looking in all the wrong places.